# Why are all the orientations written in this form - horizontal: function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y }; }. Please explain the code

Tags: javascript

The list of all the possible orientations:

```
var allOrientations = ['horizontal','horizontalBack','vertical','verticalUp',
                               'diagonal','diagonalUp','diagonalBack','diagonalUpBack'];
```

The definition of the orientation, calculates the next square given a
starting square (x,y) and distance (i) from that square.

```
var orientations = {
      horizontal:     function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y  }; },
      horizontalBack: function(x,y,i) { return {x: x-i, y: y  }; },
      vertical:       function(x,y,i) { return {x: x,   y: y+i}; },
      verticalUp:     function(x,y,i) { return {x: x,   y: y-i}; },
      diagonal:       function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y+i}; },
      diagonalBack:   function(x,y,i) { return {x: x-i, y: y+i}; },
      diagonalUp:     function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y-i}; },
      diagonalUpBack: function(x,y,i) { return {x: x-i, y: y-i}; }
    };
```

Comment: Please explain where used object `orientations` and maybe we help.

Comment: Just look at what happens if you take x=0, y=0,
horizontal goes to the right, horizontalBack goes right, vertical goes up
Each function takes a point and returns a new point shifted by i

Comment: I have understood the logic but not the syntax of the form x:x+i and y:y.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classic Navigation-Function-Selector, a common pattern in 2d games.

You can use the array of orientation-strings as the key to select from the orientation object.
That will then give you a function you can apply to your coordinates to figure out your new set of coordinates.

Here's some code of it being used, run it and look at the console, you can see how each function moves you `i` steps in the direction away from the given `x`,`y` coordinates, and returns a new `{x:__, y:__ }` object..

```js
var allOrientations = ['horizontal','horizontalBack','vertical','verticalUp',
                               'diagonal','diagonalUp','diagonalBack','diagonalUpBack'];
var orientations = {
      horizontal:     function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y  }; },
      horizontalBack: function(x,y,i) { return {x: x-i, y: y  }; },
      vertical:       function(x,y,i) { return {x: x,   y: y+i}; },
      verticalUp:     function(x,y,i) { return {x: x,   y: y-i}; },
      diagonal:       function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y+i}; },
      diagonalBack:   function(x,y,i) { return {x: x-i, y: y+i}; },
      diagonalUp:     function(x,y,i) { return {x: x+i, y: y-i}; },
      diagonalUpBack: function(x,y,i) { return {x: x-i, y: y-i}; }
    };
    

allOrientations.forEach(orientation => {
      console.log(orientation)
      
      const selectedfunction = orientations[orientation]

      current_x = 0
      current_y = 0
      step_size = 2

      const next_location = selectedfunction(current_x, current_y, step_size)

      console.log(next_location)
    }
)
```